# Tomcat is not receiving custom headers in a cross domain jquery ajax call

Tags: java, jquery, spring, tomcat, cors

I know it may seem like a duplicated question but I have not found the anwer in any of the searches here or any other site I've tried.

This is my scenario:

I am exposing an API running in tomcat over ssl in sub.domain.com. The API was developed using spring.

I am hitting the API from a client app in domain.com.

I have enabled CORS in tomcat with the folowing filter

```
<filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
    <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>ip,sessiontoken,Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Last-Modified,Authorization</param-v$
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
    <param-value>60</param-value>
</init-param></filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

In cors.allowed.headers you can see ip and sessiontoken. These are the custom headers I am using.

In the client side, this is the call I am using:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: server + apiEnpoint,
            async: false,
            headers: {
                "sessionToken": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
            },
```

This is the second request to the API. The first one which is a login request (username, password) gets through without problem. Then I call an authenticated method to retrieve user data (the previous JS).

As you can see in the image below, the server response to the preflight request is 200. But the required headers to continue with the actual request are not sent over.

[image]
This is the log in tomcat when priting the headers sent with that request:

```
ERROR: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager - org.apache.tomcat.util.http.ValuesEnumerator@65beb190
ERROR: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager - host:sub.domain.com
ERROR: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager - user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0
ERROR: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager - accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
ERROR: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager - accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.5
ERROR: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager - accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br
ERROR: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager - access-control-request-method:GET
ERROR: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager - access-control-request-headers:sessiontoken
ERROR: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager - origin:https://citywallet.net
ERROR: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager - connection:keep-alive
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@1de0bff9, returned: -1
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83)
```

Is there anything else in the configuration I may be missing?

Is there any change required in Spring?

Thanks a lot in advance. Been dealing with this for 3 days now.

Answer (score 0):

you should read the spring docs http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cors.html   and XMLHttpRequest cors https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Liaozq, Everything in the second link you shared was already considered. Regarding the first link, what's the solution in your experience? Points 26.3.1 and 26.3.2? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: the first request options is 200, so the server allow cors ,then the client will send second request ,the exception cause by spring security.not cors。my english is not very good